Mesh dissappear in object mode using rigify
What I did before was rigging the tail using rigify, and then merging the rig with the body rig (the body rig is not a rigify rig).
The tail still mesh still appear some times after that, however when I perform task like undo or changing into other collections, the tail mesh disappear. Strangely, it's still appear on edit mode, and I tried Alt + H too in case I accidentally hiding the mesh but nope, it's still disappear.
Is this a bug with rigify?
https://imgur.com/a/ZTh0GVQ

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

If it appears in edit mode only, that probably means the armature’s  deform is yeeting it out of view or scaling it very large or very small, as the modifier won’t hide the vertex’s original positions when in edit mode. Beyond that, there’s no way to tell what’s going on from the  information we have. Show us some screenshots or use blend-exchange.com to share the blend file for further diagnosis. I will ask, did you apply or clear the location, rotation, and scale for everything before merging the armatures and meshes?

Nevermind about adding screenshots, I forgot about the Imgur link, and there might be a way to tell what’s going on. I did notice though that there are two armatures. If you can, though, I think sharing your blend file will help. If you need to make the file smaller, you can drop textures in this case I think, as they aren’t related to the problem at hand.

I did not mess with anything other than moving through collections etc, so I think it's because the deformation

@TheLabCat The second armature is the underwear armature, so it has nothing to do with the tail

You WANT to clear or apply all the transforms before merging armatures, otherwise things can end up with crazy offsets. Also, unless he’s wearing long Johns I don’t think one is really for the underwear as both armatures have arm bones.

Oh pardon me, I just noticed that the second armature that you mentioned was when I press Alt + H. That armature was another rigify that I hide as a reference, not related to the tail rigify. Tho yea I'll try with apply transform first.

Turns out, the tail was assigned to 3 different armatures
Just deleting the problematic armature solves the problem
